# Describe conditions on which points $(x_{1},y_{1}) \sim (x_{1},y_{1})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ for lines with slope 2

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I want to consider the  collection  of  all  lines  with  slope  2, which forms
a  partition  of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I need to describe the conditions on which $(x_{1},y_{1}) \sim (x_{1},y_{1}).$

I think the conditions will be that $x_{i} < y_{i}$ for all $i$, and that $2x+1=y$ for all $x$ and $y >0$.  Am I on the right track to answering this question?  It seems to me like a silly question since the answer is given in the prompt (that all x and y must lie on a line with slope 2, and to me that sounds like a solid condition :) )

Answer (score 0):

If two points are on the same line with slope 2, and $y$-intercept $b$, then they both satisfy the equation
$$ y = 2x + b $$
or, written another way,
$$ y - 2x = b$$
So your equivalence relation should be $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ if
$$ y_1-2x_1 = y_2-2x_2 $$

Comment: Thanks, Nick. My only question is - why are we necessitating that points must be on the same line, when the *collection* of lines with slope 2 is what partitions $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? Don't we want to specify conditions that can apply to all lines with slope 2 (and therefore all points, I suppose), instead of a specific subset of the partition (i.e. any particular line)?  I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Usually the notation $a \sim b$ refers to an equivalence relation. An equivalence relation defines the "relationship" between elements which are to grouped together into the same "part" of a partition.